# Multiple line text and image display

Tags: javascript, html

I am in need to display a Text in two lines with an image on its right side. Something like :

```
             Image
ABCDEFGH     Image
(ABC)        Image
             Image
```

However my output is making the text come down of the image and that also in a single line:

```
<div>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<img src="images/ecg.jpg" alt="ECG" height="100" width="300" align="middle">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr class="row1">
        <td><b>Electrocardiac Diagram &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</b></td>
        <td><b>(ECG) &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
</div>
```

How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right way to do this :

```
<div style="float:left">
    <p><b>Electrocardiac Diagram &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</b></p>
    <p><b>(ECG) &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</b></p>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
    <img src="images/ecg.jpg" alt="ECG" height="100" width="300" align="middle">
</div>
```

Live Exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/dLZsQ/

Comment: could just float the image element dont need a wrapper for it

Comment: indeed but its best to do this this way so if he want like a caption for his image no probs in the future

Answer (score 0):

Add style='float:right;' to your image like this

```
<img src="images/ecg.jpg" style='float:right;' alt="ECG" height="100" width="300" align="middle" />
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TK7y3/1/)